# Jquery Range Slider calculating a different overall result over several sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to make a page with several Jquery range sliders that shows a different result than the range sliders concrete value. Look for logic, https://jsfiddle.net/f4e6zLow/3/ (Dunno why the js didn't work in jsfiddle).

I am doing the range sliders like this, and that works flawlessly in my browser, though I'm very clumsy with Jquery (As seen):

```
$('#slider-1').on("change", function() {
    $('.slider-1').val(this.value);
    }).trigger("change");

    $('#slider-2').on("change", function() {
    $('.slider-2').val(this.value);
    }).trigger("change");
```

For the estimation I've found:

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $(".add").on("change", function() {
          addAll();
        });
        addAll();
      });

      function addAll() {
        var sum = 0
        $('.add').each(function() {
          sum += isNaN(this.value) || $.trim(this.value) === '' ? 0 : parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        $('#total').html(sum);
      }
```

Whereas the range slider's HTML looks like this:

```
<input class="add" type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" min="0" max="100" value="40" />
```

And under:

```
<h1 style="font-size: xx-large;"><output for="slider-2" class="slider-2">0</output>&nbsp; -> Value should display a number different from actual value.</h1>
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle is missing the jQuery script reference: https://jsfiddle.net/f4e6zLow/5/.

Comment: Guessing I'm being blind today, in my offense I've had an exam today. Thanks though @Jasen!

Comment: But I still don't understand what you are trying to do. What is broken and what should happen instead?

Comment: Nothing is really  broken, I just want the sliders to have 1 value while display another output value. So if you send 100 messages, that can't be 100 GB of data usage. Instead it'd be like 100 messages = 0.4 gb of data.

Comment: I don't know if I understand... Run the value through a filter function `$(".slider-1").val(filterValue(this.value)); function filterValue(val) { return val + 10; }`. Have the filter return whatever computed value you want.